# A C# project cannot run on the other computers

Tags: c#

A quick question here lads, cannot run a visual studio project on another machine, receiving the CLR20r3 System.IO.DirectoryNotFound. The thing is that it has all resources needed inside the exe itself, and it's launching perfectly for me, both on debug and release versions, while crashing on any other machine. What can it possibly mean? Tried creating an installer, of course, same result. Works for me, doesn't work for others.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it really work on your machine or just inside the VS environment?  For example, if you copy the exe to a new folder and then run that directly from file explorer, does it work?

Comment: @Tintow, that is exactly what i meant, it runs separately for me, but won't run for others.

Comment: not enough information to answer this.  as a wild guess, there is some hardcode paths in the executable that don't exist on the other machines.  perhaps your program.exe.config might have some information in it..

Comment: what sort of application is it? what targetframework? do you have any MSBuild targets or runtime considerations to the application?

Comment: Alright i'll try to catch it as the Ganesh suggested below, and then try to detail it with code.
The vagueness of this problem is excatly why i turned to stackoverflow right now in the first place.

Comment: Is the application fail as soon as you run or it crashes while performing certain operations in it? Do you have exception handling and logging in application? Do you see any logs in the log files?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the directory that you are trying to find is not present on the other machine.It would be hard to find and fix this error without knowing from where exactly the exception is thrown. Better add a try catch and log the exception somewhere like a text file or a remote database. Once you are able to get hold of the line where the exception is thrown and the actual exception, it would be lot easier to fix it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

A silly mistake with not uploading properties with the project. And some weird problem with custom font, had to refer to it from properties directly. Case closed.